# CSS - Cycle through words

Tags: css

I have the following simple layout that uses CSS to cycle through phrases.

```css
.switch-text {
  position: relative;
}

.switch-text em {
  opacity: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.switch-text em:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.switch-text em:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="switch-text">
 <em>environment 1</em>
 <em>environment 2</em>
 <em>environment 3</em>
</span>

<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>

<span class="switch-text">
 <em>environment 1</em>
 <em>environment 2</em>
 <em>environment 3</em>
    <em>environment 4</em>
 <em>environment 5</em>
 <em>environment 6</em>
</span>
```

My top version works correctly, but the bottom version is overlapping elements when I add multiple items.

Anyone see why?

Comment: Probably because your code “covers” up to `:nth-child(3)`, but you added more elements than that now …?

Answer (score 1):

As you have set the animation till 3rd level you have to remove 3 list from the second list. if you need more then you have to add animation accordingly.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow');

body {
 background: #000; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
h1.main, p.demos {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
 animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 line-height: 100px;
 height: 90px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 font-size: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
 font-size: 200px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation: none;
 animation: none;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
 animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
 animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
 position: absolute;
 width: 282px;
 height: 273px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
 background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 -moz-transform: scale(5);
 -o-transform: scale(5);
 -ms-transform: scale(5);
 transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #3f1616;
 font-size: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
 background: #85373b;
 color: #fff;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-container">
 <div class="sp-content">
  <div class="sp-globe"></div>
  <h2 class="frame-1">AWESOME</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-2">TEXT ANIMATION EFFECT</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-3">BUILD WITH CSS3</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-4">TEST IT!</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-5">
   <span>FORK,</span>
   <span>CHANGE,</span>
   <span>EXPERIANCE.</span>
  </h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example with the 6 items added?

Comment: not for the 6 but i have something with multiple frame, i have update the answer please check if that's helpful.